# Should I use UUID on Graphql?

Tags: graphene-python

While I was reading Graphql official documents, I found out that Graphql uses UUID. I Googled and most examples on the internet was fetching data by using localized IDs with type names. I have no idea why the usages are different.

Only a handful of documents mentions that it is best to use base64 for encoding and decoding type:ID data sets. Is it true? Django model uses integers for primary keys and they need to be serialized in some way to be UUIDs. I am planning to use Big Int primary keys in a few of Django models. Will that approach still work for Big Int primary keys?

I found one post mentioning that I could actually use UUID in a DB level. But it seems like there is a performance issue. https://blog.hasura.io/graphql-and-uuid-type-on-postgres-767f016479e9/

Should I use UUID in a DB level, just use base64 to decode type:id, or not at all and just ask a localized ID? Even if I use a UUID, it is still exposed to clients if I follow examples on the internet, isn't it? And why do they just use localized IDs in contrast to the official document?